# “TorBrowser” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Trash

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, mac

I get this message the i try to open Tor for the first time. Ive downloaded various times and checked signatures but Mac OSx refuse to open it.
Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a quick Google search, you need to adjust your Mac security settings.

Go to the Apple icon > System Preferences > Security and Privacy > General. Click the lock icon (you will be asked for your password) and choose the option to allow apps downloaded from anywhere.

Now instead of warning you the file is damaged, it will warn you saying it was downloaded from the Internet. You should be able to click Open, and run the Tor Browser.

Source: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/45404/mac-downloaded-app-is-damaged-and-cant-be-opened-error-solved/